# Notification clock android

Tags: android, notifications

trying to create a notification on specific time

i delete the calendar attribute and it work directly after i run the app 
but when i try to set a specific time using calendar its not working at the time i set it

MainActivity

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
  import android.app.*;
  import android.*;
   import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
   import android.content.*;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.Button;

  import java.util.Calendar;

 import static android.app.PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT;


 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
  private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();



    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 48);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
    calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0,                      
     myIntent,0); 
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),     pendingIntent);

} //end onCreate



}
```

MyReceiver

```
  import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.content.Intent;
  public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
    context.startService(service1);

}

}
```

MyAlarmService

```
mport android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.IBinder;
  import android.app.*;

 /**
   * Created by osamaalammari on 4/10/15.
  */
 public class MyAlarmService extends Service {
private NotificationManager mManager;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

public void onCreate()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
}

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
{
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    mManager = (NotificationManager) 
                     this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().   

    NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent1 = new     
     Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);

    Notification notification = new 
      Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"This is a test message!",  
      System.currentTimeMillis());
    intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP|    
     Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
           PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent =    
        PendingIntent.getActivity( this.getApplicationContext(),0,  
        intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(),  
       "AlarmManagerDemo", "This is a test message!",    
    pendingNotificationIntent);

    mManager.notify(0, notification);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
 }


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
public class MyAlarmService extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        CreateNotification(context, "Forgetting something?", "Click here for more details", "Alert");
    }

    private void CreateNotification(Context context, String title, String text, String alert) {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setTicker(alert)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(text)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

                notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, notification.build());

    }
}
```

And remember to add something like this to the manifest:

```
<receiver
            android:name="yourpackagename.MyAlarmService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

And then in the class where you wish to issue your notification:

```
notificationTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyAlarmService.class);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, notificationTime, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity()
                    .getApplicationContext(), 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Notification sent!" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Did this help you out?